# Multiple processes with functions

Tags: c, unix, process, parallel-processing

I currently have a program that uses a single process to add/subtract/multiply/transpose a 2D array (matrix). This program reads two files, stores the doubles into a 2D array, and then performs the operation.

Now I am trying to separate this from a single process into x number of processes. I thought of trying to have each parent fork a child where each child opens the matrix file(s), offsets to the necessary row/column, performs the necessary operation, and returns it to the parent.

I am new to process management and I realize this isn't the most efficient way of going about this, but I was wondering how to go about executing this and if this is a correct way of going about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest and most straightforward way to do that is to use the [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) language extensions available in most  `C/C++` and `Fortran` compilers (See e.g. [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/openmp) for `gcc`.)

Processing a matrix in parallel looks like this:

```
  #pragma omp parallel for
  for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
     for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
           // process a[i][j]
```

The outer loop is then parallelized automatically in as many threads as the computer has CPUs.

The OpenMP extensions offer many options to control shared memory, workload management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly correct.  You probably want to put your matrix in shared memory (otherwise each child would be working on its own copy) and then fork your children.  If you are absolutely certain each child will only operate on its own portion of the matrix you can forgo synchronization. So something like

```
create/attach share memory

read matrix into shm

for(0..x)
{
     fork();
     if (child)
        doCalcs(some matrix subset);
}

for(0..x)
    wait();
```

Whether this is more of a PITA than it's worth is probably something only you can answer after trying it.  The other obvious option is threads but you are not necessarily reducing complexity there either.